# Karatsuba Algorithm using C

Tags: c, pointers, karatsuba

I am trying to write the Karatsuba algorithm using C. I tried my code using small numbers for example 9999 * 9999 and it is working fine however I am noticing when I increase the size of the number above 7 digits (I tried on 9999999 * 9999999 and it working fine). I realized my problem is with the pointers (after debugging). but I don't know what is the exact solution for it.

Could you please help me to find out the problem?

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    
    int length (char *);
    char *multiply (char *, char *);
    char *add (char *, char *, int);
    char *sub (char *, char *, int);
    char *addzerosl (char *, int, int);
    void reallocaddzerosl (char **, int, int);
    char *addzerosr (char *, int);
    char *karamult (char *, char *);
    void removezero (char *);
    
    
    int
    main ()
    {
        char a[] =
"3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592";
        char b[] =
"2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627";
        char *c = karamult (a, b);
    
        int d = length (c);
        printf ("%s  %d", c, d);
    
        FILE * F = NULL;
        F = fopen ("test_1.txt", "w");
        fprintf (F, "%s", c);
        fclose (F);
        free (F);
        free (c);
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Length of array
    int
    length (char *c)
    {
        int l = 0;
    
        while ((*c++) != '\0')
            l++;
    
        return l;
    }
    
    // multiply two integers
    char *
    multiply (char *a, char *b)
    {
        char *f = (char *) calloc ((3), sizeof (char));
    
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in multiply\n");
    
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        int e = (*a - '0') * (*b - '0');
        f[0] = (e / 10) + '0';
        f[1] = (e % 10) + '0';
        f[2] = '\0';
    
        removezero (f);
    
        return f;
    }
    
    // add two integers
    
    char *
    add (char *a, char *b, int n)
    {
        char *f = NULL;
        f = (char *) calloc ((n + 2), sizeof (char));
    
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in add\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        int car = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int e1 = (a[i - 1] - '0') + (b[i - 1] - '0') + car;
    
            if (e1 - 10 >= 0)
                car = 1;
            else
                car = 0;
    
            f[i] = (e1 % 10) + '0';
        }
    
        if (car)
        {
            f[0] = '1';
            f[n + 1] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            f[0] = '0';
            f[n + 1] = '\0';
    
            char *g = (char *) calloc ((n + 1), sizeof (char));

            for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                g[i] = f[i + 1];
    
            free (f);
            f = NULL;
    
            return g;
        }
    
        return f;
    }
    
    
    // sub two integers
    
    char *
    sub (char *a, char *b, int n)
    {
        char *f = (char *) calloc ((n + 1), sizeof (char));
    
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in sub\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        int car = 0;
    
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int e1 = (a[i] - '0') - (b[i] - '0') - car;
    
            if (e1 < 0)
            {
                car = 1;
    
                e1 += 10;
    
                f[i] = e1 + '0';
            }
            else
            {
                f[i] = e1 + '0';
    
                car = 0;
            }
        }
    
        f[n] = '\0';
        return f;
    }
    
    // add zeros to left
    
    char *
    addzerosl (char *a, int a1, int b)
    {
        int r = b - a1;
    
        char *f = (char *) calloc ((b + 1), sizeof (char));
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in addzerosl\n");
    
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++)
        {
            f[b - 1 - i] = a[a1 - 1 - i];
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            f[i] = '0';
        }
    
        f[b] = '\0';
    
        return f;
    
    }
    
    void
    reallocaddzerosl (char **a, int a1, int b)
    {
        int r = b - a1;
    
        *a = (char *) realloc ((*a), sizeof (char));
        if (*a == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in reallocaddzerosl\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++)
        {
            (*a)[b - 1 - i] = (*a)[a1 - 1 - i];
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            (*a)[i] = '0';
        }
    
        (*a)[b] = '\0';
    }
    
    
    // remove zeros from left
    
    void
    removezero (char *a)
    {
        int n = length (a);
        int i = 0;
    
        if (a[0] != '0')
            return;
        else
        {
            while (a[i] == '0' && a[i] != '\0')
                i++;
    
            int j = 0;
    
            if (i < n)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                {
                    a[j] = a[i + j];
                }
                a[j] = '\0';
            }
            else
            {
                a[0] = '0';
                a[1] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
    
    // add zeros to right
    
    char *
    addzerosr (char *a, int c)
    {
        char *f = (char *) calloc ((length (a) + c + 1), sizeof (char));
    
        if (a == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in addzerosr\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < length (a); i++)
            f[i] = a[i];
    
        for (int i = length (a); i < (length (a) + c); i++)
        {
            f[i] = '0';
        }
    
        f[(length (a) + c)] = '\0';
        return f;
    }
    
    
    // Karatsuba multiplication
    
    char *
    karamult (char *a, char *b)
    {
        static int de = 0;
        int la = length (a);
        int lb = length (b);
        char *ca = NULL;
        char *cb = NULL;
        int n = 0;
        char *f = NULL;
    
        if (la <= 1 && lb <= 1)
        {
            f = multiply (a, b);
            return f;
        }
    
        if (la > lb)
        {
            n = la;
            cb = addzerosl (b, lb, la);
            ca = addzerosl (a, la, la);
        }
        else if (la < lb)
        {
            n = lb;
            ca = addzerosl (a, la, lb);
            cb = addzerosl (b, lb, lb);
        }
        else
        {
            ca = addzerosl (a, la, la);
            cb = addzerosl (b, lb, lb);
    
            n = lb;
        }
    
        if (n % 2)
        {
            reallocaddzerosl (&ca, n, n + 1);
            reallocaddzerosl (&cb, n, n + 1);
            n = n + 1;
        }
    
        char *a1 = (char *) calloc ((n / 2 + 1), sizeof (char));
        char *b1 = (char *) calloc ((n / 2 + 1), sizeof (char));
        char *c1 = (char *) calloc ((n / 2 + 1), sizeof (char));
        char *d1 = (char *) calloc ((n / 2 + 1), sizeof (char));
    
        if (a1 == NULL || b1 == NULL || c1 == NULL || d1 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in a1\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            a1[i] = ca[i];
            b1[i] = ca[i + n / 2];
            c1[i] = cb[i];
            d1[i] = cb[i + n / 2];
        }
    
        a1[n / 2] = '\0';
        b1[n / 2] = '\0';
        c1[n / 2] = '\0';
        d1[n / 2] = '\0';
    
        free (ca);
        free (cb);
        ca = NULL;
        cb = NULL;
    
        char *apb = add (a1, b1, length (a1));
        if (apb == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in apb\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        char *cpb = add (c1, d1, length (c1));
        if (cpb == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in cpb\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        char *ac = karamult (a1, c1);
    
        if (ac == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in ac\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        char *bd = karamult (b1, d1);
        if (bd == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in bd\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        removezero (ac);
        removezero (bd);
        removezero (apb);
        removezero (cpb);
    
        free (a1);
        free (b1);
        free (c1);
        free (d1);
        a1 = NULL;
        b1 = NULL;
        c1 = NULL;
        d1 = NULL;
    
        char *sec = karamult (apb, cpb);
        if (sec == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in sec\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        removezero (sec);
    
        free (apb);
        free (cpb);
        apb = NULL;
        cpb = NULL;
    
        int lsec = length (sec);
        int lac = length (ac);
        if (lsec > lac)
            reallocaddzerosl (&ac, lac, lsec);
        else if (lsec < lac)
            reallocaddzerosl (&sec, lsec, lac);
    
        lsec = length (sec);

        char *sec1 = sub (sec, ac, lsec);
        if (sec1 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in sec1\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        removezero (sec1);
    
        free (sec);
        sec = NULL;

        int lsec1 = length (sec1);
        int lbd = length (bd);
    
        if (lsec1 > lbd)
            reallocaddzerosl (&bd, lbd, lsec1);
        else if (lsec1 < lbd)
            reallocaddzerosl (&sec1, lsec1, lbd);
    
        lsec1 = length (sec1);
    
        char *sec2 = sub (sec1, bd, lsec1);
        if (sec2 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in sec2\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        removezero (sec2);
    
        free (sec1);
        sec1 = NULL;
    
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
    
        char *f1 = addzerosr (ac, n);
        if (f1 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in f1\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        free (ac);
        ac = NULL;
    
        removezero (f1);
    
        char *f2 = addzerosr (sec2, (n / 2));
        if (f2 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in f2\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        free (sec2);
        sec2 = NULL;
    
        removezero (f2);
    
        int lf1 = length (f1);
        int lf2 = length (f2);
    
        if (lf1 > lf2)
            reallocaddzerosl (&f2, lf2, lf1);
        else if (lf1 < lf2)
            reallocaddzerosl (&f1, lf1, lf2);
    
        lf1 = length (f1);
    
        char *f3 = add (f1, f2, lf1);
    
        if (f3 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in f3\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        free (f1);
        free (f2);
        f1 = NULL;
        f2 = NULL;
    
        int lf3 = length (f3);
        removezero (f3);
        removezero (bd);
    
        lbd = length (bd);
    
        if (lf3 > lbd)
            reallocaddzerosl (&bd, lbd, lf3);
        else if (lf3 < lbd)
            reallocaddzerosl (&f3, lf3, lbd);
    
        lf3 = length (f3);
    
        f = add (f3, bd, lf3);
    
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in f\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        removezero (f);
        free (f3);
    
        if (bd == NULL)
        {
            printf ("error in bd\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        free (bd);
        f3 = NULL;
        bd = NULL;
    
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: I noticed that I am getting a lot of zeros on the left so I did a function that removes the zeros from the left, I was able to increase the size of the number to 11 digit however I am still having the same problem when having larger size of numbers

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/1P0ODtmEE

Comment: it seems the problem when I am freeying the pointers

Comment: You should do yourself a favor (and everyone who might read your questions in future)  and apply proper consistent indentation. Your mix of no indentation per level, negative indentation and seemingly "normal" indentation makes your code hard to read. If your text does not reflect the logical structure of the code, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh for your comments. I have updated it

Comment: Seriously? Adding empty lines everywhere and making indentation even worse will not attract a lot of people to look at that mess.

Comment: sorry it s my first time that I write a long code. I updated it again

Comment: `fclose (F); free (F);` You don't `malloc` `F`. Therefore you musn't pass that pointer to `free`

Comment: Why do you define a `length()` function that has the same effect as the standard `strlen()` function?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes I know but I didn't want to use any string functions

Comment: Well guys I knew what was the problem, it was with the realloc function, I wasn't allocating the correct size. It is working fine now